# Calculating shoot angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

My player throwing 5 knives to ground with different angles.

```
        else if (throwType == "onGround")
        {
            float angle = 15f;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Instantiate(kunai, attackPoint.position, transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, angle));
                angle += 10f;
            }
        }
```

I tryed this code but I want the distance between each of the stabbing points of all the blades to be equal on level ground. Here is the
[triangle](https://i.hizliresim.com/s3h3f2b.jpg) example that I meant.
What method or solution do I use?

Comment: Is this a 2D game?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Distribute your target points evenly along the ground, or in any other pattern.
2. Calculate the direction to each point, i.e. `point - attackPoint.Position`
3. Use [Vector3.Angle(Vector3 from, Vector3 to)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) to calculate the angle between each direction and your reference, presumably `Vector3.down`.

In general I would recommend staying away from angles when possible, and instead use methods like [Quaternion.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to create rotations from direction vectors. I find vectors much easier to reason about and visualize, but you will need at least some familiarity with vector algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I did some math, I hope it's correct and I hope it's readable! The bottom line is the underlined part, it tells you the value each throwing angle should have.

[image]